# How can I specify different file extensions as targets for multiple output files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'd like to create a set of output files from multiple input files where the output format is specified as a target. E.g., for a single format:

```makefile
svg: svg/file1.svg svg/file2.svg

svg/file1.svg svg/file2.svg: %.svg: %.dot
    @dot -T svg -o $@ $<
```

Now how can I add more formats without duplicating rules and prerequisites? My approach was something like this:

```makefile
input := file1 file2
formats := svg png
output := $(foreach format, ${formats}, $(foreach name, ${input}, ${format}/${name}.${format}))
# output := svg/file1.svg svg/file2.svg png/file1.png png/file2.png

all: ${formats}

${formats}: [somehow filter ${output} based on chosen format?]

${output}: [somehow filter out just the file name?]: %.dot
    @dot -T svg -o $@ $<
```

I haven't been able to figure this out with variables and patterns. I did find a way using a variable for the format; e.g., `make format=svg`, but I'd rather use target names.

Using GNU Make 4.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use a macro/eval for this -- but beware, by doing so, you may cross that line where your makefile can be easily understood/maintained by others.,,

```
input := file1 file2
formats := svg png
output := $(foreach format, ${formats}, $(foreach name, ${input}, ${name}.${format}))

all: $(foreach file,$(input),$(foreach format,$(foramts),$(file).$(format)))

define dot_rules
# $$1 is the basenames,
# $$2 is the input extension,
# $$3 is the target extension
$(1:=.$3) : %.$3 : %.$2
        @echo dot -T $3 -o $3/$$@ $$<


endef

# just to be suure you got it right:
$(info $(foreach format,$(formats),\
    $(call dot_rules,$(input),dot,$(format))))

# expand the calls into the makefile
$(eval $(foreach format,$(formats),\
    $(call dot_rules,$(input),dot,$(format))))
```

Comment: This is really cool, and I see what you mean about crossing that line.
A couple questions as I'm trying to _make_ this work: does this only work with the `all` target? I don't seem to be able to issue `make svg` for example.
Secondly, it doesn't seem to be expanding `$@` and `$<` correctly, not sure why. This is a sample of the output: `dot -T svg -o svg/`

Comment: Ah, I understand why `make svg` doesn't work - it's never actually defined as a target. Would need its own definition, something like `$3: $(1:=.$3)`, I think.

Comment: And to answer my own 2nd question, looks like it requires an extra escape: `$$@` and `$$<`.

Comment: Yes, sorry -- my bad -- I missed the escape on `$@` -- updating the answer.    And you are correct, you can add the line `$3: $(1:=.$3)` right in the `dot_rules` definition to create targets for the file types.